# How do I allow a semicolon in the file_header_template of editorconfig

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, editorconfig

Our file header should have a semicolon (`;`) in the text. But it seems that the `;` will be read as comment in the .editorconfig.

For example, this works:

.editorconfig:

```
; Top-most EditorConfig file
root = true
[*.cs]
file_header_template = a,b,c
```

Add -> Class, will generate:

```
// a,b,c

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NLog
{
    class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

But when using the semicolon:

.editorconfig:

```
; Top-most EditorConfig file
root = true
[*.cs]
file_header_template = a;b;c
```

Add -> Class, will generate:

```cs
// a

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NLog
{
    class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

I expected `// a;b;c` and not `// a`

How could I fix this? Is there a work arround?

I tried already (some are really non-sence):

- escaping the `;` with a backslash
- escaping the `;` with another `;`
- put the value in single or double quotes.

I think this is a Visual Studio 2019 bug, as [the specs](https://editorconfig-specification.readthedocs.io/#file-format) say:

> Comment: starts with a ; or a #.
>
> Inserting a # or ; after non-whitespace characters in a line (i.e., inline) shall neither be parsed as a comment nor as part of the section name, pair (defined below) key or value in which it was inserted. This may change in the future; thus, is not recommended.

Comment: Can confirm that this is not a Visual Studio bug. It's an editorconfig bug (or "lack of feature" might be a better description), as it happens with JetBrains Rider as well. I scoured through the source code and found that it globally determines a line comment with the regex `[#;].*`, which means # or ; followed by anything except a newline any number of times (including none). However, it also defines 3 keys to parse as raw values, with `file_header_template` being one of them, and from what I can tell, it's *supposed* to simply parse until the end of line is reached. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Okay looks like I was actually looking at the JetBrains version. The regex that the rosyln compiler uses is `^\s*([\w\.\-_]+)\s*[=:]\s*(.*?)\s*([#;].*)?$`. In any case, it essentially results in the same outcome, since the quantifier for the _value_ of the key is lazy `(.*?)` while the one for comments is greedy `([#;].*)`; the former repeats as few times as possible while the latter repeats as many times as possible. I'm with you that there should be a way to escape the comment character, but that's the way it is at this point